# Facebook App: type: GraphMethodException, code: 100, message: Unsupported get request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My Rails app tries to fetch the users photo albums:

```
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(session[:fb_auth_token])
    @albums_raw = @graph.get_connections("me", "albums")
    @albums_raw.each do |a|
        @cover_raw = @graph.get_object(a["cover_photo"])
        a["cover"] = @cover_raw["picture"]
    end
```

Before this, I am fetching the auth token:

```
[:fb_auth_token] = auth_hash["credentials"]["token"]
```

I checked my app settings and there are no age resticitons.

When I log in as a test user that only has one image (profile), the code works fine. If I log in as myself with a lot of albums, I get the error:

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1037ms

```
Koala::Facebook::ClientError (type: GraphMethodException, code: 100, message: Unsupported get request. [HTTP 400]):
  app/controllers/mixtape_images_controller.rb:43:in `block in new'
  app/controllers/mixtape_images_controller.rb:42:in `each'
  app/controllers/mixtape_images_controller.rb:42:in `new'


  Rendered /Users/svetter/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/svetter/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/svetter/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (8.6ms)
```

Does anyone have a clue what I am doing wrong here?

Thank you very much in advace!